# Gradle custom plugin depends on system task

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I hava a custom plugin called `MyPlugin` and it contains a custom task called `MyTask`. I want to make `MyTask` dependsOn `compileJava`. I tried to give `MyTask.dependsOn(compileJava)`, but it says `Task called 'MyTask' is not existing`. Is there any way to do it?

**MyPlugin.java**

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public static final String TASK_NAME = "MyTask";

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getExtensions().create(TASK_NAME, MyExtension.class);
        project.getTasks().create(TASK_NAME, MyTask.class);
    }
}
```

**MyTask.java**

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    private MyExtension extension;

    @TaskAction
    public void myTask() {
        Project project = getProject();
        extension = project.getExtensions().findByType(MyExtension.class);
        PropertyManager propertyManager = new PropertyManager(project, extension);
        propertyManager.setProperties();
        System.out.println(extension.getValue());
    }
```

**MyExtension.java**

```
public class MyExtension {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile gradleApi()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    }
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$projectDir/libs"
}

MyTask.dependsOn(copyLibs)  //not working
MyTask.dependsOn(compileJava)   //not working
```

Comment: Could you add `build.gradle` file where you apply the plugin and configure the task?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
tasks.MyTask.dependsOn(copyLibs) 
tasks.MyTask.dependsOn(compileJava)
```

because the task object you defined is not in the current scope like copyLibs. But you can access it via the tasks reference (see: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you gradle plugin isapplied to a different gradle project, say projectA, your plugin adds a task called MyTask to projectA. The build.gradle you posted above is for the plugin-project and does not have a task called MyTask.

Answer (score -1):

<s>As far as I can see your task is called `myTask`, not `MyTask`.</s>
*It was a typo in author's code.*

**UPDATE**:

You don't apply your plugin so the task doesn't get created. And you cannot apply a plugin from a plugin's `build.gradle`. At least you cannot apply a version of the plugin being build. The best you can do is to apply a previously built version of the plugin that's stored in a Maven repo. But it doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: Nope. That was actually a typo. My task name in MyTask

Comment: Are you going to fix it in your question?

Comment: I have made the changes

Comment: Added one more hypothesis to the answer.

Comment: This is the build.gradle of the plugin project.

Comment: But the plugin is not applied. You still have to apply it manually. If you want just to create a task you don't need a plugin.

Comment: Should I apply my plugin in itself? How do I o it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that because the `build.gradle` is executed before your plugin is compiled. But you can use your plugin when building itself via a Maven dependency. But it's a really dangerous way :)